# Run .sh File "Double Click" With Root Permission On Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, root

I have a bash script and i want to run it with double click on the script icon and i want to run it with root permission , and if the user now is not root , i want the script request the password root to run, or close.

Comment: Change the shebang of the script to `#!/bin/su root`.

Comment: it working only when i run it from terminal , i want to run it by double click

Comment: Your window manager will allow you to associate a script with an interpreter. Associate it with `/bin/su` and pass `root` as one of the parameters before the script.

Comment: not working in my case , i want to require a prompt window to write the root password then click ok

Comment: Now I understand what you are looking for. You are looking for something like [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/gnome-ssh-askpass.1.html).

Comment: i want something like this : http://up.dev-point.com/uploads1/62ae68daa43b1.png

Comment: On your Desktop, or wherever you want to place the icon, create a file ending in `.desktop`. Let's say you created `app.desktop` In the file  under `[Desktop Entry]` place an entry `Exec=gksu /path/to/your/script`. Of course you need to fill in the required entries for your `app.desktop`. [gksu](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) is a frontend for `su`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gksu shows a gui input box for password

```
#!/bin/gksu root
```

Comment: It's working with changing somethings , Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Simply prepend `sudo` to any commands in the script that require elevated privileges and the user will be prompted for their password if necessary.

Comment: when i use `sudo` the prompt doesn't appear !

Comment: Did a terminal window (briefly) open previously when you would run the script?  Does it still?  If so, what do you see?

Comment: my script working in the background of users system , the terminal is hidden ( running using double click on the icon of the script)